# Javascript returns only one timestamp inside for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, for-loop, time

I want to generate a timestamp for each item inside the for loop but i am getting only one timestamp inside the loop.How can i make new timestamp for each item in the for loop in javascript.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) { vm.workers[i].id = (new Date()).getTime(); }
```

This one provides only one timestamp instead of 5 different timestamp can anyone tell me how to generate multiple timestamps inside the loop.

Comment: @Li357 i am storing them as temp id

Comment: in your code store it in array or some variables.

Comment: @Li357 check my updated question

Comment: You get the same number because the loop happens so fast they each have the same value....

Comment: @epascarello so how can i have different timestamps inside the loop itself

Comment: They're all the same value due to the speed of the loop. `console.time(); for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) { console.log(new Date().getTime()); }; console.timeEnd();`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: I've retracted both my close vote and my down vote since it's a valid question that I'm sure another JS newbie will stumble upon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the ids are the same because the loop takes no time at all to run. So how can you generate a unique number for each? Add one each time you use it.

```
var ts = (new Date()).getTime();
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) { 
  vm.workers[i].id = ts++
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering the original question which had this loop:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) { new Date().getTime(); }
```

You're not doing anything with them so it will only print the last one or none at all if you're not using the console.

Try logging each one with console.log.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) { console.log(new Date().getTime()); }
```

assign them to a an array and add them like so like so will give you an array of date/time stanmps:

```
var list = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < 5; i++ ) { list.push(new Date().getTime()); }
console.log(list);
```

Comment: please try your code in you browser first; at least with a computer manufactured after 2010 :)

Comment: @no1xsyzy It seems to work in chrome dev tools https://i.imgur.com/u21dRat.png :)

Comment: that is just by accident; the loop ran from one millisecond to next one, which not *must* but *may* produce different timestamps, and in this best result, it still produces only two timestamps

Comment: @no1xsyzy, Not really. It's pushing to the array every loop so a new timestamp is generated (even though it is identical). When I answered, OP didn't specify they needed to be distinct timestamps, just that there needed to be 5 instead of 1.

Comment: That makes sense now; not noticed the time.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop iteration can certainly take less than a millisecond to complete, hence you're getting the same timestamp.

Find a more reliable way to create id's such as a [GUID](https://github.com/dandean/guid).

Here's a function, taken from [this S.O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/1814486) that creates GUID's:

```js
function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

console.log(guid())
```

Comment: the question is not that all 5 timestamps are the same, but that there is only 1 timestamp

Comment: I'm pretty sure his problem is what I answered, he's just explaining it badly

Comment: Or maybe the answer is right and the people are assuming the wrong thing. +1 since it is how I read the question.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey that was the original question before OP posted more code making it an XY Problem

Comment: @charlietfl I've explained what the problem is - I'm not gonna spoon-feed to the OP what a GUID is.

Comment: @charlietfl Even if I didn't, your comment wasn't really a good fit. A GUID is a general term that can be googled if my link gets broken. Don't be pedantic.